# Send Email Support Tickets without entering my email credentials in the source code

Tags: c#, winforms, email, send

So in my winforms application I have a support section where people could report bugs and stuff that should be sent to my email. I wonder how I could do this without entering my email credentials in the source code. A lot of people just decompile programs and then they can login to my account.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
SmtpServer.Credentials = new Net.NetworkCredential("mail@mail.com", "password123");
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
mail.To.Add("mail@mail.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress("lol@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Support";
mail.Body = "Name: " + textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Message: " + textBox2.Text;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

I wonder if there's any other way to do it.
Or if anybody know some disposable email service where you can SEND mails from without making an email account.

Comment: Agreed with Grant, you shouldn't be giving users your login credentials at all. Have them send it through their default mail app.

Comment: I basically just want a contact/support form built-in in to my program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

Make the program call a web service on a web server you control, which in turn sends the email.  This is a *much* better idea for the following reasons:

1. You don't have to embed password information.
2. Your email server, password, address, etc can all change without having to re-release the program.
3. You're no longer sending locally.  A *ton* of ISPs will block SMTP traffic locally due to spammers.  For example, I can't use SMTP with GMail because Comcast blocks that port.  I can only use Comcast's SMTP servers, which make me logon with my Comcast credentials.

If you can't make a web service, you could also open the client's default mail client and have them send the message that way.  They would use their own local mail server and logon information rather than yours.

There might be a more *official* way to do it, but you can probably just write something like:

```
Process.Start("mailto:mail@mail.com");
```

Comment: I don't know how to setup any webserver, I've never done anything that advanced yet. Any good guide on how to do it and make it send the email? Seems like a really good way to do it

Comment: Basically, just use the same code you have now.  Only, put it in a WebMethod.  There's tons of great tutorials, like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) - You might want to check out WCF as well, it's a bit more *modern* than ASP.NET web services.

Comment: You'd also need to set up a web server somewhere, which usually costs money.  There are a few *free* services, such as [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), but they'd probably require you to implement a solution in Ruby or something.  Thinking about it more, I think just popping up the user's email program is the best approach here.